# Before trigger - field not updating as expected

Tags: apex, trigger

My last question got the error fixed but now I'm not seeing the expected behavior and I'm scratching my head as to why. I have another similar trigger on another object in my org that is working just fine so I am at a loss. I do not receive any errors but my assertion fails.

If the trigger is working properly `Site_Code__c` (lookup) on the Case record should be populated with the id of the account with the matching `Site_Code_Id__c` (string)

Of particular interest, the debug log on line 4, 5, and 6; My cleaner methods (adds leading zeroes until 4 digits) appears to correctly change `2` to `0002` but then only `2` is added to `codes`.

### Stack trace from test run:

> Class.SiteCoderTest.siteCoderTest: line 61, column 1 (this is the first assert line)

### Debug log:

```
[9]|DEBUG|----SITECODER: 4 records to run
[21]|DEBUG|----SITECODER: Site code added to lookup: 0123
[21]|DEBUG|----SITECODER: Site code added to lookup: 1234
[55]|DEBUG|----SITECODER: Running cleaner on: 2
[60]|DEBUG|----SITECODER: Cleaned site code: 0002
[18]|DEBUG|----SITECODER: Site code added to lookup: 0002
[35]|DEBUG|----SITECODER: First Site Account Found: 0123
[35]|DEBUG|----SITECODER: First Site Account Found: 1234
[35]|DEBUG|----SITECODER: First Site Account Found: 0002
[38]|DEBUG|----SITECODER: Second Site Account Found: 0123
[48]|DEBUG|----SITECODER: Account found for site: null
[44]|DEBUG|SHOULD BE TRUE: false
[45]|DEBUG|Account Site Code 1: 0123
[46]|DEBUG|Case Site Code 1: 0012F00000C0IkXQAV
[48]|DEBUG|SHOULD BE TRUE: false
[49]|DEBUG|Account Site Code 2: 1234
[50]|DEBUG|Case Site Code 2: null
[52]|DEBUG|SHOULD BE TRUE: false
[53]|DEBUG|Account Site Code 3: 2345
[54]|DEBUG|Case Site Code 3: null
[56]|DEBUG|SHOULD BE FALSE: false
[57]|DEBUG|Account Site Code 4: 0002
[58]|DEBUG|Case Site Code 4: null
```

### Trigger logic:

```
public class SiteCoder {

    public static void run(List<Case> newList) {
        system.debug('----SITECODER: ' + newList.size() + ' records to run');

        Set<String> codes = new Set<String>();
        for (Case c : newList) {
            String siteCode = c.Web_Site_Code__c;
            if (string.isNotEmpty(siteCode)) {
                if (sitecode.length() < 4){
                    String cleanCode = clean(sitecode);
                    codes.add(cleanCode);
                    System.debug('----SITECODER: ' + 'Site code added to lookup: ' + cleanCode);
                } else {
                    codes.add(siteCode);
                    System.debug('----SITECODER: ' + 'Site code added to lookup: ' + sitecode);
                }


            }
        }

        // Use map and list of accounts to take into account possibility of multiple
        // accounts using same site code id
        Map<String, List<Account>> codeAccounts = new Map<String, List<Account>>();
        for (Account a : [SELECT Id, Site_Code_Id__c FROM Account 
                          WHERE Site_Code_Id__c IN :codes]) {
            if (!codeAccounts.containsKey(a.Site_Code_Id__c)) {
                codeAccounts.put(a.Site_Code_ID__c, new List<Account>());
                codeAccounts.get(a.Site_Code_ID__c).add(a);
                System.debug('----SITECODER: ' + 'First Site Account Found: ' + a.Site_Code_ID__c);
            } else {
                codeAccounts.get(a.Site_Code_ID__c).add(a);
                System.debug('----SITECODER: ' + 'Second Site Account Found: ' + a.Site_Code_ID__c);
            }
        }

        //Update the lookup only if one account matches
        for (Case c : newList) {
            List<Account> matchingAccounts = codeAccounts.get(c.Web_Site_Code__c);
            Id siteId = null;
            if (matchingAccounts != null && matchingAccounts.size() == 1) {
                siteId = matchingAccounts[0].Id;
                System.debug('----SITECODER: ' + 'Account found for site: ' + c.Site_Code__c);
            }
            c.Site_Code__c = siteId;
        }
    }

    private static String clean(String dirtyCode){
        system.debug('----SITECODER: Running cleaner on: ' + dirtyCode);
        String cleanedCode = dirtyCode;
        while (cleanedCode.length() < 4) {
            cleanedCode = '0' + cleanedCode;
        }
        system.debug('----SITECODER: Cleaned site code: ' + cleanedCode);
        return cleanedCode;
    }
}
```

### Test class:

```
@IsTest
private class SiteCoderTest {
    static TestMethod void siteCoderTest() {

        Account a1 = new Account(Name = '0123', Site_Code_Id__c = '0123');
        Account a2 = new Account(Name = '1234', Site_Code_Id__c = '1234');
        Account a3 = new Account(Name = '2345', Site_Code_Id__c = '2345');
        Account a4 = new Account(Name = '0002', Site_Code_Id__c = '0002');
        Account a1dupe = new Account(Name = '0123', Site_Code_Id__c = '0123');

        List<Account> accountInsert = new List<Account>();
        accountInsert.add(a1);
        accountInsert.add(a2);
        accountInsert.add(a3);
        accountInsert.add(a4);
        accountInsert.add(a1dupe);
        insert accountInsert;

        Case c1 = new Case(Web_Site_Code__c = '0123', Subject = 'test1');
        Case c2 = new Case(Web_Site_Code__c = '1234', Subject = 'test2');
        Case c3 = new Case(Web_Site_Code__c = null, Subject = 'test3');
        Case c4 = new Case(Web_Site_Code__c = '2', Subject = 'test4');

        List<Case> caseInsert = new List<Case>();
        caseInsert.add(c1);
        caseInsert.add(c2);
        caseInsert.add(c3);
        caseInsert.add(c4);
        insert caseInsert;

        Account ac1 = [SELECT Id, Site_Code_Id__c FROM Account WHERE Name = :a1.Name LIMIT 1];
        Account ac1dupe = [SELECT Id, Site_Code_Id__c FROM Account WHERE Name = :a1dupe.Name LIMIT 1];
        Account ac2 = [SELECT Id, Site_Code_Id__c FROM Account WHERE Name = :a2.Name];
        Account ac3 = [SELECT Id, Site_Code_Id__c FROM Account WHERE Name = :a3.Name];
        Account ac4 = [SELECT Id, Site_Code_Id__c FROM Account WHERE Name = :a4.Name];


        Case cc1 = [SELECT Id, Web_Site_Code__c, Site_Code__c FROM Case WHERE Subject = :c1.Subject];
        Case cc2 = [SELECT Id, Web_Site_Code__c, Site_Code__c FROM Case WHERE Subject = :c2.Subject];
        Case cc3 = [SELECT Id, Web_Site_Code__c, Site_Code__c FROM Case WHERE Subject = :c3.Subject];
        Case cc4 = [SELECT Id, Web_Site_Code__c, Site_Code__c FROM Case WHERE Subject = :c4.Subject];


        system.debug('SHOULD BE FALSE: ' + (string.valueof(cc1.Site_Code__c) == string.valueof(ac1.Site_Code_Id__c)));
        system.debug('Account Site Code 1: ' + string.valueof(ac1.Site_Code_Id__c));
        system.debug('Case Site Code 1: ' + string.valueof(cc1.Site_Code__c));

        system.debug('SHOULD BE TRUE: ' + (string.valueof(cc2.Site_Code__c) == string.valueof(ac2.Site_Code_Id__c)));
        system.debug('Account Site Code 2: ' + string.valueof(ac2.Site_Code_Id__c));
        system.debug('Case Site Code 2: ' + string.valueof(cc2.Site_Code__c));

        system.debug('SHOULD BE TRUE: ' + (string.valueof(cc3.Site_Code__c) == string.valueof(ac3.Site_Code_Id__c)));
        system.debug('Account Site Code 3: ' + string.valueof(ac3.Site_Code_Id__c));
        system.debug('Case Site Code 3: ' + string.valueof(cc3.Site_Code__c));

        system.debug('SHOULD BE FALSE: ' + (string.valueof(cc4.Site_Code__c) == string.valueof(ac4.Site_Code_Id__c)));
        system.debug('Account Site Code 4: ' + string.valueof(ac4.Site_Code_Id__c));
        system.debug('Case Site Code 4: ' + string.valueof(cc4.Site_Code__c));


        system.assert(string.valueof(cc1.Site_Code__c) == string.valueof(ac1.Site_Code_Id__c));
        system.assert(string.valueof(cc2.Site_Code__c) == string.valueof(ac2.Site_Code_Id__c));
        system.assertNotEquals(string.valueOf(cc3.Site_Code__c), string.valueOf(ac3.Site_Code_Id__c));
        system.assert(string.valueOf(cc3.Site_Code__c) == string.valueOf(ac4.Site_Code_Id__c));
    }
}
```

Comment: Issue with debugger line -- you output in debug logs not your entry added to list, but entry that you clean first. *clean(sitecode)* is added to list, and *sitecode* is shown in debug log. *clean* method does not change *sitecode* variable, only return updated value

Comment: I see that, thank you. I corrected that (supposedly) and also updated my test class for 100% coverage (2 accounts with same site code). 100% coverage but still failing on first assert; interestingly though the `Case Site Code` does not come out `null` but rather as the `Account Id` where I would expect the string `0123`.

Comment: I think you should take a step back,  I believe you made this extremely complicated and it shouldn't be.  It's easier for us to help you if you break down the question rather than "It's Broke"

Comment: `Case.Site_Code__c` is a lookup. It can only contain an id or be null. All the places that you are comparing it to `Account.Site_Code_Id__c` are wrong. Your first assert would pass, and be appropriately testing functionality if it compared `cc1.Web_Site_Code__c` and `ac1.Site_Code_Id__c`.